# Is there any free solution to convert a SWF video to an iPhone/iPad compatible format?

Tags: video, file-conversion, adobe-flash

I tried several programs to convert a SWF file to a video format and so far none of them seems to work.

```
4media Converter
Video xConverter
Pinguin
ffmpegx
Easy WMV
```

I expect a video in any format that I could play in iOS, like .MOV, .AVI and other. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean an FLV (Flash video) file?  That's the format you'll find in common use all over the web (e.g. YouTube).  An SWF file is typically the "player" window, and not the video itself.  Most free video conversion apps today can handle FLV files.

Comment: Are you sure the swf is a video file and not some custom flash animation? If it isnt you could try something along the lines of http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/309773-Extracting-video-from-SWF

Comment: All I know is that it is a SWF file with an video inside... and I just want to extract (or convert to) a video file

Comment: This may not be relevant to the question, but an alternative is converting on the fly. There is a project (the site appears to be down) called SmokeScreen that is supposed to convert flash to html5 on the fly. http://smokescreen.us/demos/intro.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the video is buried inside a full SWF file you won't be able to convert it -- it's much like if you had a Mac app that happens to play a built-in video: you're effectively trying to convert the app to a video, two very different kinds of things.

Instead you'll need to **extract** the video. You can use a task-specific extrator, and since you asked for a free way to do it, I suggest the [Flaex](http://afu.jf.land.to/index-en.html) app. There are a couple of other paid extractors for the Mac including [Flash Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flash-decompiler-for-mac/) and [SWF Decompiler](http://www.swf-decompiler.com/tutorial/flash-video-extractor.htm). I don't have first-hand experience with any of the extractors so I can't specifically recommend one.

The other possible not-free way to extract the video is by opening the swf file with the full [Adobe Flash Pro](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html), or have someone do it for you. Note that Adobe provides a fully-functional 30-day trial, so at least in the short-term it's a free option as well.

Answer (score 2):

Give [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) a try.

Comment: Will not work with SWF, only with FLV.

Answer (score 0):

You can jailbreak your iPhone (free), then download Cydia (free), from cydia download OpeniBoot (free), and using OpeniBoot you can install Android 2.2 (Froyo) which has flash player on it. Unfortunately, this upgrade only works on the first gen iPhone, iPhone 3G, and 1st gen iPod Touch.
That's probably your best free bet out there.
However, if you on the other hand have video, not an animation, most conversion apps (VisualHub, etc.) will do the trick.

Comment: That is not even close to an option...

Comment: Man, that is an insanely complicated way to not even solve the problem at hand.

Comment: To each his own.

Answer (score 0):

Are these videos from the internet? DownloadHelper (Firefox add-on) normally gives you options on the downloads, and there is usually a non-flash version in there.

**Edit:**
Have you tried [EasyWMV](http://www.easywma.com/wmv/)?
**Edit2:** [FlashVideo Converter](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27173/flashvideo-converter/) might do the job.

Comment: No, it is a local SWF file.. but, as I can open it with the browser, I will check if this plugin does the trick

Comment: Just saw you tried it. Sorry.

Comment: FlashVideo Converter is pricey, but try the demo.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [Adapter](https://macroplant.com/adapter). It is free and claims it will convert any format to any other format. Being free its worth a try.